# Условие видимости в Delphi

Tags: delphi, условия

Я хочу сделать программу которая при нажатии кнопки показывала бы текст, а при повторном нажатии скрывала.В чём ошибка?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);     
if Memo1.Visible then     
  begin    
    Memo1.Visible:=False     
  end     
else    
  begin    
    Memo1.Visible:=True    
  end.
```

Comment: что конкретно не работает? и что пишет компилятор?

Comment: Меня всегда _жутко бесит_, когда пишут в вопросе "не работает". Не компилируется из-за пропущенной запятой? Вылетает при старте? Обрушивает систему? В логе не появляются нужные буквы? Не открывается окно? Цвет кнопки синий, а автор хотел красный? Телепаты работают по отдельному тарифу.

Comment: Так ещё любят на собеседованиях - показать код, который написал неведомо кто под какими травами и, посмотрев, говорят "найди десять ошибок". А код такой, что не то что не скомпилируется, а блокнот упадет, когда будут вводить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что в данном случае можно не писать лишних begin/end:

```
if Memo1.Visible then        
  Memo1.Visible:=False         
else      
  Memo1.Visible:=True;
```

Во вторых, если вы скопировали реальный код, то он и не должен работать потому что:
 1. процедура не огорожена своими begin/end
 2. в конце стоит end с точкой

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Memo1.Visible then        
    Memo1.Visible:=False         
  else      
    Memo1.Visible:=True;  
end;
```

Comment: лучше писать все бегин/энды

Comment: @Сахарок, между читабельностью и захламлением кода тонкая грань. В данном примере бегины увеличивают объем кода в два раза, улучшенной читабельности они не дают, а логика и без них понятна.

Comment: я бы просто написал бы

    Memo1.Visible:= not Memo1.Visible;

А if  в данном случае - признак незнания.